# How do I specify the date locale when Dserializing YAML using YamlDotNet?

Tags: c#, datetime, deserialization, locale, yamldotnet

In a YAML document, I've got a date formatted using an EN-GB locale (so 07/02/2019 is 2nd February 2019)

When I deserialize the document using YamlDotNet, it interprets this as an EN-US date so it stores it as July 2nd 2019

```
# Date in test.yaml:
date: 07/02/2019

# Code to deserialize document to object:
var myObject= new DeserializerBuilder()
                .WithNamingConvention(CamelCaseNamingConvention.Instance)
                .Build()
                .Deserialize<MyObject>(File.ReadAllText(args[0]));
```

Is there any way to specify whihc locate should be used when dates should be converted when using DeserializerBuilder?

Comment: Just deserialize into string, then add a property getter inside the class to get the DateTime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I needed to include a call to `WithTypeConverter()` and explicitly specify the date format.

This code works:

```
new DeserializerBuilder()
   .WithNamingConvention(CamelCaseNamingConvention.Instance)
   .WithTypeConverter(new DateTimeConverter(
       provider: CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, 
       formats: new[] { "dd/MM/yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm" })
   ) 
   .Build()
   .Deserialize<MyObject>(File.ReadAllText(args[0]));
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you need to set the Culture to the Thread explicitly:

```cs
CultureInfo newCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = newCulture;
// Maybe this one below isn't necessary...
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
```

Comment: This didn't work unfortunately.